# How to apply CSS rules using attr(data-attribute)?

Tags: css, attr

I'd like to have CSS that uses attr(data-attribute) to apply a CSS-rule.

For example, in my CSS:

```
@media max-width(480px) {
  .mobile-float {
     float: attr(data-mobile-float);
  }
}
```

Then, in my HTML, I define the data-attribute:

```
<div data-mobile-float="right">
  Floats right on mobile!
</div>

<div data-mobile-float="left">
  Floats left on mobile!
</div>
```

I feel like I'm missing a character and it's not working. How do I do this correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong selector in CSS try this

```css
[data-mobile-float="left"]{font-size: 50px;}
```

```html
<div data-mobile-float="right">
  Floats right on mobile!
</div>

<div data-mobile-float="left">
  Floats left on mobile!
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but in your example, you now have to write another CSS rule for `[data-mobile-float="right"]{ ... }`. I have a lot of CSS rules that I'd like to add besides float=left / float=right / @media max-width / @media min-width, and so I'd like to use the `attr()` CSS function to provide the CSS property value.